# SetTargetObjectID dynamically

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, email-template, id

I have written a class that sends an email and I have referenced the object id (opportunity) in the URI for the VP page. So how can I make a variable that grabs that id so I can use it in my sendMail method?

mail.setTargetObjectId('XXXXXXXXX');

Thank you and please let me know if my question needs clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

proteuscanvas, if you're expecting the ID to be passed in the URL to a Visualforce page, all you need to do is use `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters()` to obtain a `Map<String, String>` of all your URL parameters (and more). Below is sample code that shows how you could use the method.

```
// Assume the record ID is contained in the the parameter named "id"

Id targetObjectId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

// Set the target object ID on the email object

mail.setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL parameter by doing the following:

`ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('yourParameterName');`

And you can do the same if you want to specify a parameter before you do a server redirect:

`ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('yourParameterName', 'yourValue');`

Comment: I am getting this error when I assign my id. 
Only Users, Contact or Lead allowed for targetObjectId : XXXXXXXX -----

 Is there something that I need to do so I can email fields to non users?